# The problem with update and subquery. one to many

Tags: mysql, sql

I get the following error update column name of my table while running this query:

```
update t1 set t1.DIST_= (SELECT SUM(t2.amount) as DIST_ FROM t2
                         WHERE unique_number =300291 and t2.reseller_id ='31')
```

i have 2 table(t1 and t2)
t1 have column DIST_ and unique_number and 1 row
t2 have many row and column amount, unique_number, reseller_id

This request must calculate the amount from table t2 with t2.reseller_id='31' and write value to t1.DIST_ by unique_number

Now request changes the values of all table column, but I need to update only column where t2.unique_number=t1.unique_number

Comment: Don't store calculated values depending on other table data. Create a view instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like below using join

```
   UPDATE TABLEA t1 
       JOIN (SELECT unique_number,SUM(t2.amount) as DIST_ FROM table2
            group by unique_number
            ) t2 ON t2.unique_number=t1.unique_number
       SET t1.DIST_ =t2.DIST_
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a `WHERE` clause in the `UPDATE` statement:

```
update t1 set t1.DIST_= (SELECT SUM(t2.amount) as DIST_ FROM t2
                         WHERE unique_number =300291 and t2.reseller_id ='31')
where t1.unique_number = 300291
```

If you want to update all rows of `t1` to the corresponding sum from `t2`, join with a subquery that groups them.

```
update t1
JOIN (SELECT unique_number, SUM(amount) AS DIST_
      FROM t2
      WHERE reseller_id = '31'
      GROUP BY unique_number) AS t2
ON t1.unique_number = t2.unique_number
SET t1.DIST_ = t2.DIST_
```